# Fast base64 decoding in GWT

Tags: iphone, gwt, base64, jsni

I have the following performance problem when decoding base64 on iPhone 4S. I'm decoding a "blob" of size roughly 80K. The native function for this, atob(), is very fast and completes in a few ms. However, the result of this is a string where the character code (as obtained using .charCodeAt()) of each character in the string represents one byte of the binary data that was base64 encoded. I want to convert this to a byte[], but this seems to be a very slow process on  especially iPhone's. Just running through the array and calling .charCodeAt() on each character and storing that in e.g. an UInt8Array takes 1.2 seconds on an iPhone 4S - even though we are talking about only 80K and the base64 decoding has already been done - it's the character to byte decoding that takes this long. The performance penalty is the same if one instead parses the decoded string (i.e. output of atob()) back to GWT and do the conversion to byte[] there (again by a loop). So what I'm looking for is either:

1. A fast way to convert the string that results from atob() to byte[]. It seems converting them character-for-character using charCodeAt() is way too slow compared to what such an operation should take.
2. A fast base64 to byte[] decoder which doesn't rely on atob() but can natively generate the byte[].

Unfortunately the alternatives I've tried for #2 were even slower (factor 3x) than the other method.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do, out of interest?

Comment: The data source in question only delivers B64 so it has to be decoded on the client. However, see my own response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more experimentation it turned out that the String -> Uint8array conversion really isn't as slow as was indicated before, it was due to another programming bug. So the 1,2 seconds were really only around 40 ms. So from my POV this can be closed.